# Is there software to calculate/plot decomposed rotation curves from observational data (FITS, etc)?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, dark-matter

I have observation data of galaxies (in FITS format). From the FITS data, I want to calculate & plot the decomposed rotation curves as pictured below. Is there a software package that will do that (preferably in Python)?

Context: I'm interested in finding the radial mass distribution of the dark matter in each galaxy. If there is already a database or catalog of this, then telling me that would be even better.

[Image from: Roos, Matts. (2010). Dark Matter: The evidence from astronomy, astrophysics and cosmology. ]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "observation data"?

Comment: ;I’m voting to close this question because it was double posted and has an answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/628564/is-there-software-to-calculate-plot-decomposed-rotation-curves-from-observationa/628698#628698

Comment: @ConnorGarcia Yes, I agree. I sent a message to the moderators yesterday. Is it possible to link this question to the other stack exchange?